# Sorting directories returned from opendir()?

Tags: php, directory

I'm trying to iterate through a list of folders, but I can't seem to figure out an easy way to get `opendir()` to return sorted records like `scandir()` can. How can I sort directories opened with `opendir`()?

Comment: Why don't you use `scandir()`, when you know, that it will do, what you are looking for?

Comment: Or just sort `glob('*',GLOB_ONLYDIR);`?

Comment: You could also use `glob` but not sure what you are getting at / doing so it may not be practical.

Comment: I considered that, but the output from the two functions are very different and my code uses the output of opendir().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option would be to store dir names in an array and then use a sorting function.

```
<?php
$directories = array();

$dh = opendir('./mydir/');
while ($dir = readdir($dh)) {
    $directories[] = $dir;
}
closedir($dh);

print_r(sort($directories));
```

Answer (score 4):

If scandir fits your needs, you can use it. If for whatever reason you cannot use scandir, you can store the directories in an array and sort that array using one of the many sorting functions.

Answer (score 1):

opendir() does not have a sorting option, sadly.

If you have to have sorting, you will need to use scandir(). :(